# Generic declaration of member variables

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

is there any way to declare a variety number of member variables from different user-data type generically using template operator?

consider this code:

```
    class a {
              int member;
             void ProcessMemberVariable ();
            };
    class b {
              char member;
             void ProcessMemberVariable ();
            };
... // arbitrary number of such classes



    class test {

    template <typename T>
    void declare (T a ) {
    // each time this member function is called a new member variable of the
    // user data type T shall be declared  in the instance of the class test?? 
    }
    };

int ()
{
test Test;
Test.template declare<a>(a A);
Test.template declare<b>(b B);
...
}
```

Imagine You want to implement an interface which is apple to set any kind of user defined data type. Since I know the identifier of user-defined data type only when I declare an instance of class "test"  and call its member function...

I appreciate each suggestion..

Comment: Could you show an example code using `declare` and the effect of such?

Comment: How about using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) to store the "variables"?

Comment: If this was possible, how could you write code to access a member variable whose name is unknown? You could use a `std::vector`, or similar, to create new instances and the instances would be individually accessible.

Comment: I still don't understand. `Test.template declare<a>(a A);` is not valid C++, so I don't know what do you mean. What happens to `A` after this statement? Does this have any relationship with those `member` or `ProcessMemberVariable()`?

Comment: I want to store A form the user data type as a member variable..You can imagine that you want to insert an instance  with arbitrary  member variables belonging to different user data types during a member function call

Comment: Normally you have all the members that you might need defined inside the class instead of adding them dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @sam so you want a `vector` of `variant`'s?

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing sounds like dynamically adding members to an object, and this isn't possible in C++.  There are various ways to get a similar effect in certain situations, but you would need to describe a situation where you thought this would be useful.

Comment: I meant a more specific use case.  A case that made you want to add members at runtime.

Comment: Andrei Alexandrescu explores an interesting approach to adding members at compile-time using template meta-programming in Modern C++ Design - Chapter 3.13 Class Generation with Typelists.

Answer (score 2):

As stated there is no way to dynamically add member variables at runtime.

However, if you know the list of types that you may want to add at runtime you could achieve this behaviour using boost::variant. Below is a trivial example (

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
       typedef boost::variant< long, double, string > VariantType;

       template< typename T > 
       void Declare( std::string name, T val )
       {
          VariantType newVal = val; 
          varMap.insert( std::make_pair( std::move( name ), std::move( val ) ) );
       }

       VariantType Get( const std::string& name )
       {
           return varMap[ name ];
       }

       template< typename T > 
       T GetValue( const std::string& name )
       {
          return boost::get<T>( varMap[name] );
       }

    private:
       std::map< string, VariantType > varMap;
};


int main()
{
    Test t{};

    t.Declare( "Var1", 10l );
    t.Declare( "pi",  3.14159);
    t.Declare( "AString",  "SomeName" );

    cout << "t.get( Var1 ) " << t.GetValue<long>( "Var1" ) << "\n";
    cout << "t.get( pi ) " << t.GetValue<double>( "pi" ) << "\n";
    cout << "t.get( AString ) " << t.GetValue<string>( "AString" ) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant.html for details on how to use boost::variant.